# How do I create enums in Python 3.11+ with no arguments passed to __init__?

Tags: python, enums, python-3.9, python-3.11

I have the following code, which works as expected on 3.9 and 3.10:

```py
from enum import Enum


class Environment(Enum):
    DEV = ()
    INT = ()
    PROD = ()

    def __init__(self):
        self._value_ = self.name.lower()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_url(self):
        if self is Environment.DEV:
            return 'http://localhost'
        else:
            return f'https://{self.value}.my.domain'
```

Here is the result in a REPL:

```py
>>> Environment.DEV.get_url()
'http://localhost'
>>> Environment.INT.get_url()
'https://int.my.domain'
>>> Environment.PROD.get_url()
'https://prod.my.domain'
```

I did this because I read that defining an `__init__` method for enums allows passing tuples when assigning values, and I wanted to avoid the redundant/error prone explicit declarations such as:

```py
    DEV = 'DEV'
    INT = 'INT'
    PROD = 'PROD'
```

Now, when I run the same code on Python 3.11 or 3.12, every call to `get_url` returns the localhost URL. Trying it out in the REPL, we get:

```py
>>> Environment.DEV.get_url()
'http://localhost'
>>> Environment.INT.get_url()
'http://localhost'
>>> Environment.PROD.get_url()
'http://localhost'
```

I even noticed that all of the enum values are equal to the first one:

```py
>>> Environment.DEV
<Environment.DEV: 'dev'>
>>> Environment.INT
<Environment.DEV: 'dev'>
>>> Environment.PROD
<Environment.DEV: 'dev'>
```

Has something changed in python 3.11 which makes using empty tuples at assignation forbidden/broken? How could I get the same result in those versions, i.e. declare the enum values without having to explicitly pass any argument to `__init__`?

Comment: How is `DEV = 'DEV'` "error prone"? This is a standard practice. The whole point is to restrict values to those which are expected. This by no means answers your question, but asks why not follow decades of convention.

Comment: This looks like a new optimization. Since the values are the same, it doesn't create different instances.

Comment: @MichaelRuth: Because it forces you to write the names twice, and more repetition increases the chances you'll mistype something.

Comment: @user2357112, are we seriously worried about the ability of a programmer to copy/paste `DEV` into source code? I mean, this is why code review exists. I doubt that any pro will miss `DEV = 'PROD'`. I realize this is counterproductive, but are you actually suggesting to disregard decades of adherence to a standard in order to satisfy some desire to prematurely optimize for storage which is relatively free? Especially in a language which likes to abstract away implementation so that the user can do what makes sense.

Comment: @MichaelRuth @user2357112 [`auto()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.auto) exists for that purpose.

Comment: @MichaelRuth: The OP is not trying to optimize for storage. Besides, `DEV = 'DEV'` isn't even "standard" anyway - standard would be to use `DEV = 1` or `DEV = auto()`.

Comment: @InSync, `auto()` would turn `DEV` into `dev`, but generally it should reduce errors which should be caught in review.

Comment: @user2357112, re-reading this makes me agree with you. This isn't some misplaced attempt to optimize for storage. It's a misplaced attempt to avoid a dev not being able to write `DEV = 'DEV'`, or `DEV = 'dev'`. Definitely still a good question about Python internals though.

Comment: @user2357112 is right: the idea was to avoid typos. You could even go as far as saying that there might me a zero-width space somewhere in the string, causing issues (although I'll admit that is is very far-fetched).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `auto()` and [`_generate_next_value_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum._generate_next_value_):

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Environment(Enum):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        return name
    DEV = auto()
    INT = auto()
    PROD = auto()
```

This will automatically generate values based on the names.

Note that while `_generate_next_value_` is currently documented as a staticmethod, applying the staticmethod decorator is optional, and didn't work on previous versions - previous versions required a bare function.